# Jquery - change <span>text</span> with dropdown selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This might be easy, but I'm a JQuery dunce and keep getting errors!

Basically, I have a basic JQuery 1.4+ function that updates an input value - but now I'm having a hard time figuring out how to also use JQuery to simultaneously update a text in the  area when different values are chosen with a dropdown selector. The Script and HTML looks like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mycups3').change(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();

    $('#myhidden3').val(x);
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="myhidden3" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="" value="Button" />
  <select id='mycups3'>
    <option value='1'>1 Item</option>
    <option value='2'>2 Items</option>
    <option value='3'>3 Items</option>
  </select>
  <span>$1.50</span>
</form>
```

What I want to add:
When using the dropdown selector, I also want the value in the `<span>$1.50</span>` to update. Example - selecting a value of '1' makes the text string in `span` show $1.50 - selecting a value of '2' in the dropdown makes the text string show $3.00 (or whatever) etc!

Any clues are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I saw a few suggestions where people get the value of the dropdown and multiply it by 1.5  Remember to use parseInt() on x before using it in an expression.  Use - parseInt(x) || 0 - where 0 is your fallback if x fails to parse (returns Nan)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>     
    $(function() {         
        $('#mycups3').change(function() {             
            var x = $(this).val();             
            $('#myhidden3').val(x);         
            $(this).next("span").text("$" + (x * 1.5).toFixed(2));
        });     
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Yes! This was a good way of doing it.  Just one question though - in the case that the result is $4.5 - how to ensure that another '0' is added to make it $4.50 ? I guess it's a formatting issue, so I'm trying to experiment with .toFixed();  ?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest adding an id to the span then doing something like this:

```
 $('#spanID').text($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the .html() function after you selected the span you want to modify e.g.:

```
$('span').html('$'+(x*1.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text() function to set or get the text of an HTML Element (does not work on input fields!). Your code example might look like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    $('#mycups3').change(function() {
        var x = $(this).val();
        $('#myhidden3').val(x);
        $('form span').text('$'+(x*1.5));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/fyFxp/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#itemQuantitySelect_3').change(function() {

        var itemPrice = 1.50;
        var itemQuantity = $(this).val();
        var quantityPrice = (itemPrice * itemQuantity).toFixed(2);

        $(this).next("span").html("$" + quantityPrice);

    });
});
```

I've changed your HTML a bit (more understandable field names/IDs), but you should  get the basic idea.

I also removed your hidden field as I see no point in duplicating data. Your selected value from the select box will already be sent to the server and then you have an hidden field that does exactly the same.

You can get the quantity server-side with the keyword itemQuantity_3 (in PHP $_POST['itemQuantity_3']).

Answer (score 0):

use html method.

```
$('span').html("$1.50");
```